# Send html answer from PHP to Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I use an Ajax call to select messages from my database, I echo the content in my PHP and i try to get the echoed html in the Ajax success. But it does not work. Here is the code.

**JQUERY:**

```
function SelectMessages() 
{
    console.log("Selecting messages");
    console.log("Talk = " + talk);

    $.ajax({
        url: "select_messages.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: "talk=" + talk,
        success: function (html) { 
            alert(html);
            console.log("In success");
            $("#message_box").prepend(html)
        },
        error: function (html) {
            alert(html);
            console.log("In error");
        }
    });//ajax()

}//SelectMessages()
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    //SELECTING MESSAGES   
    require 'dbconnect.php';

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Content-type: application/json');    

    if ($_GET['talk'] != "") {
        $request = $bdd->prepare('SELECT AUTHOR,CONTENT FROM MESSAGE WHERE  TALK = :talk');
        $request->execute(array("talk"=>$_GET['talk']));        

        while ($data = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo' <p> '.$data['CONTENT'].'</p>';
        } 
    }             
?>
```

Using this code, I get "In error" displayed on the console and the code in the alert is "[object Object]". However, the status of my query is "OK" in my browser and the echoed result in the network window is the one expected with all the right values of messages.

I just don't understand why I get through the error instead of success.

Please do not mark this as a duplicate as I have already checked and tested the Ajax/PHP solutions and did not get any result.

Comment: Remove `header('Content-type: application/json'); ` !!

Comment: what about talk vairable ? how did you assign value to it ? and remove the headers from php file

Comment: More of a json issue i suppose, since you are getting it as `object object`

Comment: 1.`Remove header('Content-type: application/json'); !! ` .2.in php before `if `add `$final_data = '';` 3. in while write `$final_data .=' <p> '.$data['CONTENT'].'</p>';` 4. outside side `if` write `echo $final_data;` and check once

Comment: Rémy Kaloustian  please check the answers below and let us know the final status. if resolved then mark and up-vote one answer which is correct. up-vote others too if they are useful. thanks

Comment: I just removed    `header('Content-type: application/json');`  and it worked ! Thanks a lot, you just saved my life !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php file you have set content type header as follows

```
 header('Content-type: application/json');
```

but normally echoed the response as plain text/html. Either you have to send the response in json.

```
echo json_encode($data['CONTENT']);
```

Or remove content-type header as json.

Comment: Sorry, but he can't use `echo json_encode($data['CONTENT']);` inside the while loop ! He must first collect all data then echo the JSON encoded ! However, I don't see any need of json encoded data here !!

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH But I don't think that loop will occur more than once however i've also given an alternate solution.

Comment: I removed the `header('Content-type: application/json');` and it worked. Thanks anyway !